# Redux Saga vs useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-saga

I am going to learn Redux Saga library. Maybe I need to go deeper in it but I have one question: Do we need React Saga in case of React Hooks (e.g. useEffect as side effect hook)? If yes, can you give a little example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux saga is a middleware for redux, which means that it will manipulate the action before it goes to the reducer. It does not matter if you use the hooks or class api, the question of using redux-saga depends on the particular project.